# How to solve NullReferenceException while handling an array and ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, arrays, observablecollection, nullreferenceexception

I have encounter the stated exception in my codes. Then I search online for this exception and have done what I can, creating an instance, making the elements to be added to an ObservableCollection. Probably the NullException comes from personID[0]? But for array, it always start from 0.. Like an array of 8 is from 0 to 7. I couldn't figure out why this exception persist. Could you please lend a helping hand to me? Your help will be much appreciated and thanks a lot in advance.

```
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                if (this.PersonIdDetails == null)
                    PersonIdDetails= new ObservableCollection<PersonId>();
                else
                    this.PersonIdDetails.Clear();

                var lineCount = File.ReadLines(fileName).Count();

                PersonId[] personId = new PersonId[lineCount];

                int y = 0;

                while (file.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    string line = file.ReadLine();
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) continue;
                    //To remove the whitespace of the to-be-splitted-elements
                    line = line.Replace(" ", "_");

                    char[] charSeparators = new char[] { '§', '�' };
                    string[] parts = line.Split(charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    personId [y].QualName = parts[1]; //the exception is throw here. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".
                    personId [y].ID = parts[2];
                    personId [y].Use.UserUse = true;
                    GetWriteablePropertyUser(personId [y], Convert.ToInt32(parts[3]));
                    GetReadablePropertyUser(personId [y], Convert.ToInt32(parts[3]));

                    PersonIdDetails .Add(personId [y]);

                    y++;
                }
            }
```

As seen from the code, I wrote "PersonId[] personId = new PersonId[lineCount];" an instance in an array to solve the exception, but the problem still persist. If it's because y = 0, that means if I have an array of 120, then i can only have 119 elements filled? Thank you for your time.

Comment: why you reading parts[1] etc..? Shouldn't it start at parts[0]?

Comment: Because part[0] is "L", and normal code for every line of the file, so I ignore it.

Comment: How about debugging? Throw in some breakpoints, hit that F5 Button and behold! Thou shalt see the line where the exception is thrown!

Comment: I set the breakpoint and check the lines. Actually for the parts there are no problem. I intended to show it in WPF, after read from the txt.File. It's the problem with the "personId", right?

Comment: Put the breakpoint at the exception line and check the parts array.

Comment: the array got number of 220, but it's null null ... for all of them. Shouldnt it be null, when I want to read from txt.File and save it inside, then it's not null? sorry if I have misunderstand some part.

Comment: Why are you using the `personId` array at all?  You just add the `PersonId` class to the `PersonIdDetails` class after you populate it, so what purpose does the array have?

Comment: Erm. Because the PersonIdDetails is an ObservableCollection. That was how I think before, because everytime the personId read a new line and have the new QualName. Then the latest QualName will be updated to all other previously saved QualName also. Let say my third QualName is Christ, I will have three elements with the same QualName "Christ" in the PersonIdDetails (ObservableCollection), so I have decided to make it an array. Or do you have a better suggestion? =)

Comment: The older part of the project has been using PersonIdDetails for so long to show out the table via WPF. So I don't change it to List<T>. ObservableCollection<T> will also save the changes that has been made right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the line

```
PersonId[] personId = new PersonId[lineCount];
```

PersonId is a class (reference type) so when you create the array, all the elements are initialized to null.  You need to create an instance for each array element.

One way to do that would be to insert this line immediately before the line that throws the exception:

```
personId [y] = new PersonId();
```

Comment: I see. So if I have 200 in the array, it's better to create an instance for each of them separately, right?

Comment: Actually before that my personId is not an array. But when I set breakpoint to check the elements saved inside the PersonIdDetails (ObservableCollection), it always save the current one. Like the 3rd one got QualName of Stephen. I will have the same name "Stephen" for all three elements. ObservableCollection also save changes applied to personId and applied to all the previous saved one right?

Comment: @user3481276 you need to create 200 separate instances at some point.  You could do it in a separate loop before the main loop, or you could do it in the main loop.  The second option seems like less code to me, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: @user3481276 that's because you have many references to the same instance stored in your collection or your array.  You need to create new separate instances if you want to avoid this.

Comment: Thank you @phoog, I understand my problem and figure out what's the best solution for me now. =)